# open particular page in Adobe Reader from application with specific constraints

Tags: android, pdf, adobe-reader

i open a pdf file from my app in Adobe reader, now...

-> if i want to open to open n'th page of the pdf from my application into Adobe reader.. can i do that?? [i want to keep track of the page number that was last viewed & open the pdf from there...wen viewed next time]

-> can i open the Adobe reader in the middle body of the screen, & have my Application's name at the top & my Menu Options??

Comment: Please only ask one question per post. I'll answer your first question. Perhaps you can delete your second question and ask it again as its own question.

Answer (score 1):

For Adobe Reader and Adobe Acrobat on the desktop Adobe products some [open parameters](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf) that let you control various initial view properties when a PDF is opened. If Adobe Reader for Android supports this feature then the same open parameters will be used.

For example:

- http://example.org/doc.pdf#page=5 -- would open the PDF at page 5
- http://example.org/doc.pdf#pagemode=bookmarks&page=4 -- would open the PDF at page 4 with the bookmarks panel open

Unfortunately if Adobe Reader for Android does not recognize the above open parameters as being valid then what you are trying to do is not possible using a simple URL. Instead you would need to a 3rd party SDK to open the PDF adjust the initial view settings (page number, zoom, page mode, etc) and then re-save the PDF and open it for viewing. Not a simple process.

Comment: Good thinking, but no, the Adobe Reader for Android does not support this feature.

Answer (score -2):

it is very simple. On the lower left corner there is the page number. If you do not see it
touch this place and the page number will appear. For example if you are on page 54 in a file 200 pages long you will see 54/200. You touch the number 54 and a request "Go to page" will appear with a supporting touch keyboard. You print the page number and OK.

Comment: This does not answer the question. This involves the user interface and is not a programmatic solution.